# locationfound triggers before map is ready

Tags: leaflet

So I'm following the example on Leaflet documentation about Leaflet maps for mobile, but I have a problem with the onlocationfound event.

It's been triggered but when I call the map from the function it's undefined. I'm using it on Angular.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  myMap: L.map;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myMap = new L.map("myMap").fitWorld();

    let oMap = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      maxZoom: 21,
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
      attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Google Maps'
    });
    oMap.addTo(this.myMap);

    this.myMap.locate({ setView: true, zoom: 16 });

    this.myMap.on('locationerror', this.onLocationError);
    this.myMap.on('locationfound', this.onLocationFound);

  }


  onLocationFound(e) {
    console.log(this.myMap);
    let radius = e.accuracy;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(this.myMap)
      .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(this.myMap);

  }

  onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Error is:

```
core.js:5871 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
    at NewClass.addTo (leaflet-src.js:6559)
    at NewClass.onLocationFound (map.component.ts:42)
    at NewClass.fire (leaflet-src.js:593)
    at NewClass._handleGeolocationResponse (leaflet-src.js:3742)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:365)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41271)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Zone.runGuarded (zone-evergreen.js:134)
    at zone-evergreen.js:118
```

And this.myMap is showing on console as undefined.

Comment: This is not a race condition, it's a scope problem. Put a `console.log(this)` in `onLocationFound()` and prepare to be surprised. Then, read about [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Thanks, it was confusing to see the error, but now I got it working by invoking the call to the function is a different way ;)
I have read about this before, but I don't get used to it.